# Django/Python - Delete function in UpdateView is duplicating rather than deleting

Tags: python, django

i have created a Django app that allows users to enter their stock trades, as a journaling tool. When a user clicks on an individual journal entry from the index page, they will be taken to a detail page showing all the information on that individual entry (single_entry.html). This page is handled by an UpdateView. From this page, a user can edit/update any info, as well as DELETE that specific entry. To accomplish this, I've imported the DeletionMixin module from django.views.generic.edit.

However, when I click on the "Delete" button in the form, the entry is duplicated instead of deleted! Does anyone know why that's happening?? Thanks for your help!

Here's my class based view in views.py:

```
class SingleEntryView(UpdateView):
  template_name = "single_entry.html"
  model = Entry
  fields = ['ticker', 'strategy', 'result', 'comments', 'image']
  success_url = '/'
    
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "delete_button" in self.request.POST:
      return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
  def update_post(self, form, pk):
    if "update_button" in self.request.POST:
      form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super(SingleEntryView, self).update_post(form)
```

single_entry.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Trading Journal - Entry
{% endblock title %}Trading Journal

{% block content %}

<form method="POST" action="/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {{field.label_tag}}
        {{field}}
        {% if field.errors %}
            <small class="error">{{ field.errors|striptags }}</small>            
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" name="update_button">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" name="delete_button">Delete</button>
    
</form>

<img src="{{ entry.image.url }}" alt="{{ entry.result }}">

{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.EntryView.as_view()),
    path("entries/<int:pk>/", views.SingleEntryView.as_view(), name="single-entry"),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls)
]
```

Asking ChatGPT for help, it recommended the follwing code in my UpdateView(which gave me the same problem):

```
  def post(request, self, form):
    print("post request")
    print("request.post", request.POST)
    if "delete" in request.POST:
      print("delete found")
      return self.delete_entry()
    else:
      print("else statement")
      #return super(SingleEntryView, self).post(request, form)

      return super().post(request, form)
      #return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)      

  def delete_entry(self):
    entry = self.get_object()
    print("get object")
    entry.delete()
    messages.success(self.request, "Your entry was deleted successfully.")
    return redirect("/")
```

Heres my models.py:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.utils.text import slugify


    class Entry(models.Model):
        ONEORB="1-Min ORB"
        FIVEORB="5-Min ORB"
        ABCD="ABCD"
        REVERSAL="Reversal"
        PROFIT="Profit"
        LOSS="Loss"
        RESULT_CHOICES = (
            (PROFIT, "Profit"),
            (LOSS, "Loss")
        )
        STRATEGY_CHOICES = (
            (ONEORB,"1-Min ORB"),
            (FIVEORB,"5-Min ORB"),
            (ABCD,"ABCD"),
            (REVERSAL,"Reversal")
        )

        entered_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        ticker=models.CharField(max_length=8, default="")
        strategy=models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=STRATEGY_CHOICES, default="ONEORB")
        result=models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=RESULT_CHOICES, default="PROFIT")
        comments=models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to="", null=True, blank=True) #will save to default BASE_DIR which is 'uploads'

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.result} {self.entered_date}"
```

Comment: Can you share the model, did you cange the `.save()`/`.delete()`? What is `update_post` doing? This is not linked "out of the box" in an `UpdateView`.

Comment: Just posted it above. update_post was just searching for the button named "update_post" in single_entry.html. If it found that name in the HTTP Post request then it would trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here. The first one is that you do not *route* back to your view, you should make a POST request to the same path, so:

```
<!-- no action 🖟 -->
<form method="POST">
    <!-- … -->
</form>
```

in the view, you should handle the delete scenario with `self.object.delete()`:

```
class SingleEntryView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'single_entry.html'
    model = Entry
    fields = ['ticker', 'strategy', 'result', 'comments', 'image']
    success_url = '/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'delete_button' in self.request.POST:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            self.object.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: Since [**PEP-3135** <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), you don't need to call `super(…)` with parameters if the first parameter is the class in which you define the method, and the second is the first parameter (usually `self`) of the function.

Comment: Thanks willeM, what do you mean by 'route back to your view'? I'm just not clear on that.  Where is this code supposed to go: ```<!-- no action  -->
<form method="POST">
    <!-- … -->
</form>```

Comment: @AndreDiCarlo: if the form is submitted, it should visit the same path, to trigger the `SingleEntryView` a second time. By using `action="/"`, it triggers the `EntryView` instead. Likely you have a `CreateView` over there? So then it creates a record, not updating the existing one.

Comment: Thanks I didn;t realize I was routing it back to my CreateView! That caused the duplication. I tried your code for the post method, but now I'm getting this error: Exception Type: ValueError at /entries/37/
Exception Value: The view entries.views.view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: @AndreDiCarlo: are you sure you did not forget a `return` in a `super()` call?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say the error I am getting is: 'SingleEntryView' object has no attribute 'object'

Comment: @AndreDiCarlo: aarrghhhh, yes. I forgot that, edited.

Comment: Awesome it worked! Thanks so much. I set it as the answer

Comment: Hey @willeM_ Van Onsem, one question i have is: what does this line do: what is it returning exactly, is it trying to update the post? ```return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)```  If so, I'd like to be able to call the form_valid method instead. Basically whats happening now is, the Image does not get updated for some reason, but the other attributes get updated fine

Comment: @AndreDiCarlo: the HTTP response that the `UpdateView` will generate, so it will pass the request to the form, check if it is valid, if so save the form, and return a redirect, otherwise render a template with the failed form.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, looks like you are trying to handle the deletion of the entry within the `post()` method of your `SingleEntryView` class. But the `DeleteView` provided by Django already handles the deletion logic, so you don't need to override the `post()` method for deletion. Now modify your code like this :

```python
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic import DeleteView

class SingleEntryDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = "delete_entry.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, "Your entry was deleted successfully.")
        return super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Now it will handle the deletion process, and entry will be deleted without duplication.**

And in your `single_entry.html`, you can create a link or button to the delete view, like so :

```html
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'single-entry-delete' entry.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Ensure you have a corresponding URL pattern in your `urls.py` for the `SingleEntryDeleteView`:

```python
from django.urls import path
from .views import SingleEntryDeleteView

urlpatterns = [
    path('entries/<int:pk>/delete/', SingleEntryDeleteView.as_view(), name='single-entry-delete'),
]
```

Now it should work fine. Happy Coding!

Comment: But now I have to create a new template called 'delete_entry.html' right? Thats what I was trying to avoid. Won't that bring the user to a new screen? I'm surprised there isnt an easier way to do this in Django

Comment: Thanks so much! Finally working! One additional question though, in my html template, I added the following code in addition to the snippet you posted above. Basically now I have two forms in my single_entry.html. I guess theres no other way to do it, right? Here's what I entered:    ```<form action="/entries/{{entry.id}}/delete" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="{{entry.id}}">
    <button>Delete</button>
</form>```

Comment: Hi saroosh, i responded to your post above